# Posting in a form using CURL PHP

Tags: php, forms, jquery, curl

this is the form:

```
<textarea name="message" id="messageContent" rows="18" wrap="virtual" tabindex="2"></textarea>

    <span id="formSubmit">
<a href="#" class="formSubmit" tabindex="3">
<img src="/clear.gif" class="master-sprite sprite-pm-send">
</a>
    </span>
```

the formSubmit class is an Ajax function I tracked down on the source code, I used Fiddler to capture the params I needed to POST and found this:

```
callCount=1
c0-scriptName=PostFunctions
c0-methodName=insertPost
c0-id=1894_1310435282892
c0-param0=number:1578007
c0-param1=string:Hello%20World!
xml=true
```

Hello World! was what I wrote on the textarea and posted, fiddler also found a cookie on header, not sure if I need to use it. Can someone help ? I'm trying to post that for 2 days now, this is really making me crazy ! thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the formSubmit class is an Ajax function"? formSubmit is just the class attribute of the HTML element.

Comment: I don't know, i'm just lost in that, i'm just learning curl and in this case it's not an regular form, there is no "submit" button, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

request the page and split the cookie in http headers response 
Example:

```
//get the cookies 
$ch = curl_init("url"); 
$opts = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true
            ); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts); 
$res = curl_exec($ch); 
preg_match_all("/set-cookie:\s*([^\n]+)/i",$res,$cookies); 
$cookies = implode(";", $cookies[1]); 

//send the post with cookies in headers 
$ch = curl_init("url"); 
$opts = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CUOROPT_COOKIE => $cookies, 
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params
            ); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts); 
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```